# WPF : How to bind StackPanel height (which is auto) to ImageControl height?

Tags: binding

I have stackPanel created in design (xmal) which has Auto height and width. Adding list of image controls dynamically in Code on Load to stackPanel. Now it works fine. But when i try to resize the window, though the stack panel gets resized due to auto, but not the image contrl.

How to bind the actualheight of stackpanel dynamically to image control height, (so when ever stakpanl height gets changed ,image control also should get changed !!).

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx#Y31738)

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Viewbox MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="500" Name="vb1">
        <Image Source="tulip_farm.jpg"/>
    </Viewbox>    
</StackPanel>
```

[How to: Apply Stretch Properties to the Contents of a Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752301.aspx)

Or you could use binding as below:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel">
    <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="{Binding ElementName=MyStackPanel, Path=ActualHeight}"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But in my case, I add N no of Image control dynamically in Code behind. Not in Xmal. So in that case how do we bind ?

Comment: below is the code snip ,
//after reading the image files, add it to stack panel
foreach (string strFile in ArrStrFiles)
{
// display the file names here 
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit(); 
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(strFile);
bi.EndInit();
Image img = new Image(); 
img.Source = bi;
img.Width = 170;
img.Height = stkPanl.ActualHeight; 
img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill; 
img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

Comment: Border border = new Border(); 
border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
border.Child = img;
stkPanl.Children.Add(border);
}

Comment: Please update your question with code. It would be much more readable.

Comment: Plz find the code snip in the above comments. Though it look like paragraph :) due to char limit.

Comment: +1 for Path=ActualHeight -- that was the piece I was missing.